# TypeError: User.findByIdAndUpdate is not a function

Tags: javascript, mongoose, promise

**Answer**
this fixed: `mongoose.model('User').findByIdAndUpdate(...` although it doesn't seem right. Should be another way to require this. Will figure out.

I have a signup form, where user can check a role to either create a candidate or an employer account. Let's say, user picked employer, then mongoose post hook will be triggered to create an employer inside employer collection and return employer._id so that I can save it to user collection as reference. In the last code snippet, `findByIdAndUpdate` is not triggered and failed silently. Log, outputs only `a`.

user.js (user model)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

const {
    updateUserWithEmployerId,
    updateUserWithCandidateId
} = require('../api/user');

const { createCandidate } = require('../api/candidate');
const { createEmployer } = require('../api/employer');

const userSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    password: String,
    role: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['candidate', 'employer']
    },
    _employerId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Employer'
    },
    _candidateId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Candidate'
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

userSchema.post('save', function(doc, next){
    if(doc.role === 'employer'){
        return  createEmployer(doc._id)
                .then(response => updateUserWithEmployerId(doc._id, response.employer._id))
                // .catch(error => next(error))
                // .catch(error => response.status(500).send(error))
    }else if(doc.role === 'candidate'){
        return  createCandidate(doc._id)
                .then(response => updateUserWithCandidateId(doc._id, response.candidate._id))
                .catch(error => response.status(500).send(error))
    }else{
        throw new Error('User role not found!');
    }
    next();
});

const ModelClass = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = ModelClass;
```

employer.js(this is not model)

```
const Employer = require('../models/employer');

exports.createEmployer = (userId) => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        const employerInstance = new Employer({ _userId: userId });

        if(employerInstance){
            employerInstance.save((err, employer) => {
                if(err){
                    reject({ message: "Error occured while creating employer!" });
                }else{
                    resolve({ employer: employer });
                }
            });
        }else{
            reject({ message: "Error occured while creating employer!" });
        }
    });
};
```

user.js (not a model)

```
const User = require('../models/user');

exports.updateUserWithEmployerId = (userId, employerId) => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        console.log("a");
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, { _employerId: employerId }, { new: true },
        (err, user) => {
            console.log("user:", user);
            if(err){
                console.log("b");
                reject({ message: "Error occured while updating user with employer id!" });
            }else{
                console.log("c");
                resolve({ user: user });
            }
        });
        console.log("d");
    });
};
```

Comment: use this `var User = require('mongoose').model('User');` in the file where you're getting error. let me know if this helps

Comment: no need to do `const User = require('../models/user');`

Comment: using first, outputs: MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "User". and second one is: User is not defined.

Comment: Ok. require  `user.js` where you've defined your `user model` in your server.js file. something like `const User = require('../models/user');`

Comment: take a look at this https://github.com/usman154/movieApp

This will give you an idea of how to make rest apis. This is what you are trying to do. right ?

Comment: and don't forget to add a star to that repository :D

Comment: I've updated the question with server.js file

Comment: this should resolve the issue. 
1- var User = require('mongoose').model('User'); in `user.js` file
2- `require('../models/user');` in server.js file

Comment: I don;t know why you still facing issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168132/discussion-between-usman-rana-and-cyonder).

Comment: `mongoose.model('User').findByIdAndUpdate(....` this works but import statements don't work. I don't get why.

Answer (score 0):

Server is working on http:4000
Mongodb connected with server: localhost
C:\Ajay Vemra\Mern Stack E-Commerce Website\backend\controllers\productController.js:41
product = await product.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,req.body,{
^

TypeError: product.findByIdAndUpdate is not a function
at exports.updateProduct (C:\Ajay Vemra\Mern Stack E-Commerce Website\backend\controllers\productController.js:41:29)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).